# Android - Animate canvas.DrawLine

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I know this question has been asked few times already, but I did not find anything that works.

I have a class that extends `View` and all I want to do is simply animate a draw line.

```
canvas.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2, linePaint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating the `stopY` value and drawing next frame until `stopY` reached to a certain point.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   if (startY >= endY) {
       canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, startY, linePaint);
       // draw next frame
       startY = startY - 1;
       invalidate();
   } else {
       canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, endY, linePaint);
   }
}
```